# Sending a Tuple object over WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, datamember

Is the `System.Tuple` class supported by WCF's Data Contract Serializer (i.e., can I pass `Tuple` objects to WCF calls and/or receive them as part or all of the result)?

I found [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx), but not the clear, definitive "you can send and receive Tuples with WCF" answer I was hoping for.

I'm guessing that you can, as long as all of the types *within* the `Tuple` itself are supported by the Data Contract Serializer -- can anyone provide me with a more definitive answer? Thanks.

Comment: Tuples should work fine in WCF as long as the types inside the tuple are basic types, not custom ones.  If so, then it will cause a circular dependency on the client because the client will not be a Tuple<T>, it will be TupleT.  I'm having issues with this now.  Generic in web services seems to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Tuple` types are marked with `SerializableAttribute`, therefore, if the types you store within are serializable, they should be able to be serialized by WCF as well.

Check out: links of [Tuple'1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386941.aspx), [Tuple'2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx), etc. It says:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class Tuple<T1> : IStructuralEquatable, IStructuralComparable, IComparable, ITuple
```

Note that the document you linked contains the following line:

> The [Serializable] / ISerializable programming model is not supported in a partial trust environment.

So, it may not be as easy as it would seem.

(BTW, the [Tuple static class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) is also worth checking out.)

Answer (score 9):

I was just digging into this myself, and it seems that one issue might be if you're consuming the WCF service through Silverlight: see [Davy Brion's blog](http://davybrion.com/blog/2010/06/more-on-system-tuple-and-serializationdeserialization/) for more.

The Silverlight version of Tuple doesn't have the Serializable attribute, which poses an issue at present.

Answer (score 5):

I have Tuples working nicely with .NET 4.0 and WCF (reminder: you need .NET 4.0 for Tuple support).

Here is the unit test method (which calls the method via the WCF layer):

```
/// <summary>
/// Test Tuples
/// </summary>
[TestMethod()]
public void WcfTestTupleUnit()
{
  Tuple<double, double> x;
  x=CallViaWCF.testTuple();
  Assert.AreEqual(x.Item1, 42);
  Assert.AreEqual(x.Item2, 43);
}
#endregion
```

Here is the interface:

```
[OperationContract]
Tuple<double, double> testTuple();
```

Here is the implementation:

```
public Tuple<double, double> testTuple()
{
  return new Tuple<double, double>(42, 43);
}
```

I just tested it by debugging using a "WCF Service Application" (see New..Project), which serves the WCF service. I use this method for debugging, as I can use the debugger to step seamlessly from the WCF client into the WCF service , and back again, which is quite useful at times.

I've also just tested this method by deploying it to both a console app, and a service app, so its definitely working for me.