# Alternative for NameValueCollection to be used in serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary, datacontractserializer, namevaluecollection

I have a situation where in I cant use a Dictionary for name value collection of strings. My name value pair contains duplicate keys, because I need to support a legacy system. So please don't ask me to stop supporting duplicate keys. I tried to use NameValueCollection but this cannot be used with DataContractSerializer as it throws exception. [Refer to the question for the error details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939118/wcf-serialization-problem-using-namevaluecollection)

Can anybody suggest alternative for this NameValueCollection type so that I can store key value pairs (only strings)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* translate the name-value pairs into a `List<Tuple<string, string>>`, which according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732840/sending-a-tuple-object-over-wcf) is serializable.

Of course, you lose protection against duplicates, so you should only use this to get it across the wire.